# Node.js async/await not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I am Korean and I do not speak English well so I ask for your understanding.

I am creating code that takes a search word and page number and crawls it.

```
let promises = []; //promise save
let totalData = []; //final data

let makeRequest = function(url) { 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(url, function(err, response, body){
      if(body == null) { return reject('fail'); }

      const $ = cheerio.load(body);
      let parsingData = $('.g .r a');
      console.log(parsingData);

      for(let i = 0; i < parsingData.length; i++){
          totalData.push(parsingData[i]);
      }

      return resolve('success');
    });
  });
}

//promises push
for(let i = 0; i < pageCount; i++){
  let url = `https://google.com/search?q=${ searchWord }&start=${i}0`
  promises.push(makeRequest(url));
}


(async function(){
  try{
    await Promise.all(promises);   
    console.log(totalData); 
    return res.json(true);
  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error);
    return res.json(false);
  }
});
```

I have confirmed that all promises change from pending to resolved.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FksMO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J22Qa.png)

I also noticed that the data I imported into the crawl was normal.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnz5c.png)

But I do not know why async and await do not work. console.log (totalData); does not execute.

Comment: `console.log (totalData); does not execute` neither does anything inside that anonymous function you've created and discarded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This portion:

```
(async function(){
  try{
    await Promise.all(promises);   
    console.log(totalData); 
    return res.json(true);
  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error);
    return res.json(false);
  }
});
```

Looks as if you're trying to create an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), but in this case you have created an anonymous function but you don't invoke it. So none of the code inside that function will execute. You need to add an extra set of parentheses to the end of that to invoke the function:

```
(async function(){
  try{
    await Promise.all(promises);   
    console.log(totalData); 
    return res.json(true);
  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error);
    return res.json(false);
  }
})(); // <-- note the extra () here
```